# Mongodb How to Store Only FileName

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb.  Is it possible that I store only file name in Mongodb and Store that file outside db in file system . If possible then how? Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Comment: storing a file name is anything like storing a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a sub document like below for every file you want to store. A suggestion.

```
{
   'filename' : 'abc.txt',
   'filepath':'/files/abcRelated/abc.txt'
}
```